# GDB backtrace don't show function names on Mac

Tags: objective-c, debugging, macos, gdb, backtrace

I was testing some things with gdb with this code (it's a wrong code, i use it just for testing purposes):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int i = 1;  

    NSLog(@"Hi GDB, i is %@", i);

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Then i compile it : `gcc -Wall -g -framework Foundation testGdb.m -o testGdb`, and i run it:

```
gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries ..... done

(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/Tarek/Desktop/a.out 
Reading symbols for shared libraries .++++....................... done

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x000000000000002a
0x00007fff82d7a0a3 in objc_msgSend_fixup ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff82d7a0a3 in objc_msgSend_fixup ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

(gdb)

The strange thing is that ther's no name in (#1), the correct output would normally print NSLog(the cause of the crash) and main.

Thanks for helping to understand this strange behavior.

Comment: you have debug symbols available for your code but not for the shared libraries.

Comment: Why this? can you explain to me the cause. Thanks.

Comment: @funnycoder per default, debug symbols are stripped from all shared libraries to save space `strip(1)`. If you have the possibility, compile them yourself using the "-g" flag. To check if debug-symbols are present use `nm -a /path/to/library`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean!! i'm talking about a simple program(not a library) and i'm linking just with the Foundation Framawork.when i run nm command all symbols are present.

Comment: I can’t explain exactly why but it’s related to how the compiler and runtime optimise certain method calls in Objective-C 2.0 on x86_64 — there’s an internal vtable that’s used instead of the traditional Objective-C message dispatch mechanism. For some reason, the method fixup code prevents the debugger from reconstructing the stack trace. If you compile your code with `-arch i386`, which doesn’t use vtables, you’ll be able to get the back trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522227/gdb-stack-strangeness) answer is most likely applicable here as well.

Debug symbols have nothing to do with the problem -- GDB can unwind stack just fine without them (only unwind descriptors are necessary).

Comment: If i understand your answer in the previous post, i can conclude that (the Mac OS X Objective-c Library) does not have the unwind descriptors? Is this problem is specific to X86_64? Thanks.

Comment: It likely does not have *correct* unwind descriptor for the objc_msgSend_fixup function (it may have unwind descriptors for other functions in that library). The problem is x86_64 specific in that GCC doesn't use frame pointers in optimized code on that architecture. GCC 4.6 doesn't use frame pointers on i*86 either, so the problem will (eventually) spread there as well.